# Where can one find Microsoft Host Integration assemblies?

Tags: .net

For example, MSDN references the Microsoft.HostIntegration.SNA.Session.dll assembly [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.hostintegration.sna.session.sessionlu0.aspx).

- Doesn't appear to be in GAC or found through the simple "Add Reference" menus
- Is not included in the [Host Integration Server SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41557) even though the samples it contains reference it.
- I couldn't find it on an actual Host Integration Server (Maybe I didn't know where to look)
- I couldn't find it searching Nuget
- Last resort, I couldn't find it via Google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HostIntegration .NET assemblies can be found on the Host Integration Server itself in the GAC folders